# Rails/rspec method doubles instead of any_instance.stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have a project which is now using RSpec 3, but still contains (now deprecated) RSpec 2 syntax for stubbing methods.

Currently we extensively use:

```
Class::OtherClass.any_instance.stub(:method)
```

These are called from a Simulation module that is included in an ActiveRecord model (this is important in a second).

The methods in the simulation are called from within the specs, based on whether the application should run its specs for real, or in mock mode.

So, the simulation module ends up looking something like this:

```
module Foo::Simulation
  def break_baz!
    Foo::Bar.any_instance.stub(:baz).and_raise(ArgumentError.new("You broke your baz!"))
  end
end
```

I'm trying to convert this to use doubles, but I cannot figure out the equivalent syntax for doubles.

Can anybody help me out with doubles in a way that would replicate the behavior of `any_instance.stub`?

**EDIT 1**

The closest I've come so far is:

```
module Foo::Simulation
  def break_baz!
    allow(self.baz).to receive(ArgumentError.new("You broke your baz!"))
  end
end
```

But when the object id changes when I post to a controller, the method is no longer stubbed.

**EDIT 2**

This is as much code as I can provide:

```
class Provider
  include Provider::Simulation

  def iam
    Fog::AWS::IAM.new(credentials)
  end
end
```

Then the simulation:

```
module Provider::Simulation
  def break_server_certificates!
    Fog::Mock.any_instance.stub(:upload_server_certificate).and_raise(new_error)
  end
end
```

The spec:

```
it "should not upload a server certificate" do
  provider.break_server_certificates!                   # provider is defined and is an instance of the Provider AR model
  client.post provider_server_certificates_path, params #client is a rack client that we use to test api interactions
end
```

Now, the problem is any time I change the `any_instance.stub` in the simulation to use a double, particulary a [partial double](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/partial-doubles), which is the closest I've been able to get, with something like this:

```
def break_server_certificates!
  expect(self.iam).to receive(:upload_server_certificates).and_raise(new_error)
end
```

The method sticks, but since my test does a real API interaction, which finds the provider in the controller again, it is not the same instance of `Provider`, so of course the method is back to default.

Answer (score 0):

Stubs for test doubles in RSpec 3 are made with `allow`:

```
foo = double("foo")
allow(foo).to receive(:baz) { "baz" }
```

But you can also define the allowed methods by suppling a hash when creating the test double:

```
foo = double("foo", baz: "baz")
```

Comment: I've been messing with allow, and it might be the gem that provides the method that I'm trying to stub that is messing me up.  Anytime I do something like that, I end up getting a `Class does not implement: method` error, even though I know it does.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared more code we could see what's going on? One thing to look out for it that the right object is being stubbed. `any_instance` is handy because it will affect anything returned through a `find` on the model -- if you want to replace `any_instance` you'll need another way to attach the stub.

Comment: Thanks, sorry it took me so long to get back to you.  I've edited my original question, see everything below Edit 2.  Any advice you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you calling `Fog.mock!` in the test setup?

Comment: Yeah, but fog mocks don't implement the feature that I need, which is why I've been reduced to stubbing it in my application.

Comment: It sounds like you're in an uphill battle here. Have you considered mocking out all network calls with Webmock or VCR?

Comment: I don't think that would really fix the problem I'm having right now.  The code itself works, and it works with the old rspec any_instance.stub.  I'm just not sure how to use it in the new world.  I assume rspec will completely deprecate that in the future, otherwise I would keep using it.

Comment: The functionality is still present in RSpec 3, as `allow_any_instance_of` and `expect_any_instance_of`: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance. Its use is discouraged, but I don't see a way around it in your case, unless you go the route of intercepting all network calls and replacing with mocks *a la* Webmock.